# What is max capacity of JasonArray in datatable with performance leakouts?

Tags: java, jsp, datatable, datatables

I am using [datatables](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/359750/jQuery-DataTables-in-Java-Web-Applications#ServerSideProcessing) in my Jsp to paginate records from database. However I want to know maximum capacity of JasonArray *custJasonArray* used. I am attaching my code snippet here, maximum how many records I can put in *custJasonArray* without affecting performance of the application?

```
        JSONArray custJasonArray= new JSONArray();

        for (custRecord c : RecordsList) {
            JSONArray row = new JSONArray();            

            row.put(c.getId());
            row.put(c.getName());
            row.put(c.getRole());
            row.put(c.getLikes());              
            custJasonArray.put(row);
        }
        jsonResponse.put("aaData", custJasonArray);

        response.setContentType("application/Json");
        response.getWriter().print(jsonResponse.toString());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer you are searching for is pretty subjective. There is no maximum of what you can put in. The performance issue comes on to the client browser when initializing the datatable. Generally the better processor you have, the faster will display.

But there are other issues affecting the performance, for example what your records consist of. If a record consist of values `1,2,3,4,a,b,c,d` and you have a thousand records, that might have the same performance with 5,000 records containing just `1,2,3`.

In my experience, a record with approximately 300 characters can work well until a couple of thousand records. Above that, you will get a nasty behavior from your browser.  If you are dealing with a large dataset you must take into consideration the [ajax](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/ajax.html) option provided by datatables. Thats for sure.

Comment: I have records with 13 columns, all String 13-40 chars, can jasonArray hold such 10 thousands records without affecting performance?

Comment: jason array can hold, but you will have some performance issues mainly coming from the number of columns. Why dont you consider the ajax option?